# Different versions of destructor called depending on strange factors

Tags: c++, c++11, linker, shared-ptr, boost-optional

Why do the following code generate such output?

```
main.cpp ctor 0x24a4c30
test.cpp dtor 0x24a4c30
```

*test.cpp*

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

struct Test
{
    Test()
    {
        printf("test.cpp ctor %p\n", (void *) this);
    }

    ~Test()
    {
        printf("test.cpp dtor %p\n", (void *) this);
    }
};

boost::optional< Test > t;
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include <memory>

struct Test
{
    Test()
    {
        printf("main.cpp ctor %p\n", (void *) this);
    }

    ~Test()
    {
        printf("main.cpp dtor %p\n", (void *) this);
    }
};

int
main(void)
{
    std::make_shared< Test >();
    return 0;
}
```

*Compiled with*

```
g++ -std=c++11 -c test.cpp -o test.o
g++ -std=c++11 -c main.cpp -o main.o
g++ -std=c++11 test.o main.o
```

I explain this behaviour that the *test.o* provide Test's *ctor & dtor* then a linker discard duplicated symbols from *main.o*, but it's correct only for *dtor*. If I delete the static object *t* then a linker discard symbols from *test.o* and the output is next

```
main.cpp ctor 0x208ec30
main.cpp dtor 0x208ec30
```

Comment: This program violates One Definition Rule, the behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, defining the same symbols in two linked translation units violates the [One Definition Rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition), and while

> **There can be more than one definition in a program**, as long as each
>   definition appears in a different translation unit, of each of the
>   following: **class type**, enumeration type, **inline function with external
>   linkage**, inline variable with external linkage (since C++17), class
>   template, non-static function template, static data member of a class
>   template, member function of a class template, partial template
>   specialization, concept (since C++20) as long as all of the following
>   is true:
>
> - **each definition consists of the same sequence of tokens** (typically, appears in the same header file)
> - [...]
>
> If all these requirements are satisfied, the program behaves as if
>   there is only one definition in the entire program. Otherwise, **the
>   behavior is undefined**. *(emphasis mine)*

Observed results of UB don't need explanation, and may not have any.

Sure, this is a blatant violation. However, a very similar situation can appear (and cause strange and hard to locate bugs) in more innocent-looking programs. For example, linking against an older separately compiled object when some class declarations changed.

Comment: These are inline functions, you have completely the wrong quote.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks! Better now?

Comment: Yes, much better, although you ought to also bold "inline function with external linkage" because those are in play here.  Best of all would be to put your answer on the original question this one is a duplicate of.